# Java Streams: Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I am using streams to concatenate a series of strings and add commas between them, but there must be no comma at the beginning or the end of the result string.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class QuestionNine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new QuestionNine().launch();
    }
    public void launch(){
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Hello", "Bonjour", "engine", "Hurray", "What", 
                                           "Dog", "boat", "Egg", "Queen", "Soq", "Eet");
        String result = (words.stream().map(str -> str + ",").reduce("", (a,b) -> a + b));
        result = result.substring(0, result.length() -1); //removes last comma
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Instead of using the `String.substring()` method at the end to get rid of the last comma, is there a way i could have deleted the last comma within the stream pipeline?

Comment: Just use `String#join`. Or collect the stream with `Collectors.joining(",")`

Answer (score 3):

The usual idiom is to use the joining `Collector` with Streams.

```
String res = words.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Although you can use `String.join` in your case since you are directly dealing with an `Iterable`.

```
String res = String.join(",", words);
```

The problem with your approach is that the mapping function you apply impose that there will be a comma at the end of each word. You could get rid of this mapping; and apply the reduce function such that you get the desired output:

```
.stream().reduce("", (a,b) -> a.isEmpty() ? b : a+","+b);
```

but I don't recommend this.

Comment: Or: words.stream().reduce( (a,b) -> a + ", " + b).orElse("");

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `Collectors.joining()` here:

```
String joined = words.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Or, also as noted from comments, you can use newly added [`String.join(CharSequence, Iterable)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) method.

```
String joined = String.join(", ", words);
```

Comment: With guava: `Joiner.on(", ").join(words);`